# Unable to detect "Enter key" in Javascript with Php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am working with php and javascript, I have texarea and i want whenever i enter any text and
press "Enter key" then alert should display,But right now text is going to next line instead of display alert box,

Here is my html code

```
<textarea  placeholder="Write a comment1…" id="txt'.$FeedId.'" rows="1" class="reply_post_new" style="overflow:hidden" onkeypress="return Addcomment1(this)"></textarea>
```

And here is my script code,Where i am wrong ?

```
<script>
function Addcomment1(e) {
    f (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Hello world');
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that you are passing the textarea element to the function instead of the event object.

Your other issues are that you are using an intrinsic event attribute (which comes with a bunch of gotchas) and the deprecated `keyCode` property. You also made a typo and misspelt `if`. Finally, function names starting with a capital letter are traditionally reserved for construction functions, which yours isn't.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('keypress', addComment1);

function addComment1(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    alert('Hello world');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Write a comment1…" id="txt'.$FeedId.'" rows="1" class="reply_post_new" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

---

And all that aside, since you have a single line `<textarea>` where you are blocking the use of the Enter key… you should probably get rid of the JS and just use `<input type="text>` instead.

Comment: I have two different textboxes in same page so how can i manage both textareas ?

Comment: Call `addEventListener` on each of them.

Comment: you mean "document.querySelector('#your id '); "

Is this right ?

Comment: That's one option. I'd probably give them class names and do it in a loop instead.

Comment: How can i get "document.querySelector("#your id"); " value in loop ?

Comment: You wouldn't, that's why I said I'd use a class name instead.

Comment: Your code not working in my side, Still text going to next line after press "Enter key" instead of alert

Comment: There's a live demo in my answer which works. I can't tell what you've done wrong applying it.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `this` in the function `Addcomment1(this)` returns the element itself, not the key event that you wish to get so you must use javascript `addEventListener` to get the event key and use `key` instead of `keyCode` as it is a deprecated property

HTML:

```
<textarea placeholder="Write a comment1…" id="txt'.$FeedId.'" rows="1" class="reply_post_new" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
let textarea = document.querySelector('.reply_post_new');

textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Hello world');
        return false;
    }
});
```